# Removing dimensions from array

Tags: java, arrays

I am dealing with arrays of dynamic dimension, and I have to create a method that removes a specified dimension so that the sum of all elements in the array don't change.

For example:

```
[[18, 7], [11,19]]
```

Removing dimension 0 results in [29, 26]
Removing dimension 1 results in [25, 30]

I have used the row major order to convert to a flat array and calculate the offsets:

```
int offset = dimensionIndices[dimensionSizes.length - 1];
          for (int d = dimensionSizes.length - 2; d >= 0; --d) {
            offset = offset * dimensionSizes[d] + dimensionIndices[d];
          }
          return offset;
```

I am really unsure about how to proceed with removing the dimensions and distributing the values across other elements.

I would appreciate some advice on how to go about doing this.

Update for some 3D example:

```
array = createArray(2, 2, 2);
        int value = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
                    array.setValue(value, i, j, k);
                    ++value;
                }
            }
        }
```

Represented in row major order results in:

```
[0, 4, 2, 6, 1, 5, 3, 7]
```

Removing dimension 0 should give:

```
[4, 8, 6, 10]
```

Removing dimension 1 should give:

```
[2, 4, 10, 12]
```

Removing dimension 2 should give:

```
[1, 9, 5, 13]
```

Comment: So replacing each inner array with the sum of it?

Comment: Can you have higher dimensions than 2x2? How would removing the dimensions work on 3x3?

Comment: @Aleksandar I have edited to include 3D example

Comment: do all dimensions have the same length, ie is it always square/cube/multicube?

Comment: @Lashane yes always square, cube etc

Comment: @Benirving92 can you provide expected answers for all 3 dimensions in 3D case?

Comment: Sorry @Lashane can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: @Benirving92 you provided sample 3D array, and output in case of dimension 1 removal, what should be in case of dimension 0,2 removal?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104578/discussion-between-benirving92-and-lashane).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after playing some time I come to this variant:

```
    public int[] removeDimension(final int dim) {
        /**
         * flatArray - original row-major order 1D representative of ND matrix
         * dimLength - length of one side
         * dimCount - number of dimensions
         */
        final int[] result = new int[flatArray.length / dimLength];
        for (int i = 0; i < flatArray.length; i++) {
            /**
             * construct array of original indexes, used to fill this value.
             * replace dimension which should be removed with -1.
             */
            final int[] indexes = new int[dimCount];
            for (int j = (dimCount - 1), ti = i; j >= 0; j--) {
                indexes[j] = (j == dim) ? -1 : (ti % dimLength);
                ti /= dimLength;
            }

            /**
             * construct final index in N-1D matrix, just skip removed dimension.
             */
            int idx = 0;
            for (final int index : indexes) {
                if (index != -1) {
                    idx = (idx * dimLength) + index;
                }
            }
            // summarize values into cell
            result[idx] += flatArray[i];
        }
        return result;
    }
```

for 2D test data it returns:

```
29  26  
25  30
```

for 3D test data:

```
4   6   8   10  
2   4   10  12  
1   5   9   13
```